# How to include file *.php in Bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header design template in folder: `/template/header.php`. In the header.php file I'm using Bootstrap.

Then I created another file in the folder: `/karyawan/karyawan_form.php`

In my karyawan_form.php INCLUDE file header.php file

So karyawan_form.php script file like this:

```
<?php
include_once '../template/header.php';
?>
<div class="container">
Welcome to my website!
</div>
```

Then it does not run on localhost with the link:

> localhost / belajarajax / karyawan / karyawan_form.php

But why the yard look like ordinary PHP view; like no Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
include_once '../../template/header.php';
```

I think

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/template/header.php';
?>
```

Comment: @itoru `print_r(dirname(__FILE__));` and then set the path destination correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The stylesheets and scripts propably aren't loaded on the including page. Change the links in your `header.php`. Try to change the link references in your header.php, for example:

```
/template/src/bootstrap.min.js
/template/src/bootstrap.min.css
```